# Jquery load() .aspx page without form tag and view state

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css

I am loading a .aspx page on a div using

```
http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/external.html
```

I have written page load on aspx page.
 Everything is working fine. But the CSS of the base page changes as I close the aspx page (dynamically loaded).
 Also I wanted to know that can I load the page without the form tag and view state value.
 I have also tried page view state property.
The page has page load event written.

Kindly suggest me.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're asking. What have you tried already? What's not working?

Comment: I have a two pages. A.aspx and B.aspx. I am loading B.aspx on A.aspx. I have written some some CSS on A.aspx and B.aspx. And using API of above site to open the B.aspx on A.aspx. Everything woks fine it get loaded. But when I click on that div (containg B.aspx) some of my A.aspx page css get removed autometically.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the `load` method you can use the `get` method

```
$.get("B.aspx", function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {                
                $("#result").html($(responseText).find("#container").html());
            });
```

You can use a selector to get only the content you need from `B.aspx`. The `form` tag contains the viewstate input also, so I think is better to add a div inside it ( I gave it the id `container`).

You can use also and the load method, but it will contain and the `div` itself

```
 $("#result").load("B.aspx #container");
```

This loads the `B.aspx` page and adds to the `#result` what finds on `#container` including the element itself.